# Implementing a streak counter in Polars

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to come up with the most idiomatic/elegant way to do a streak counter in Polars - either streaks of consecutive values or of consecutive rows in which a given condition is met. For example:

| person_id | order_id | item | streak_counter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alice | 1 | A | 1 |
| bob | 2 | B | 1 |
| alice | 3 | B | 1 |
| bob | 4 | B | 2 |
| alice | 5 | A | 1 |
| bob | 6 | B | 3 |
| alice | 7 | A | 2 |
| bob | 8 | A | 1 |

In PySpark I would do something like

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

partition_cols = [F.col("person_id")]
order_cols = [F.col("order_id")]
window_spec = Window.partitionBy(partition_cols).orderBy(order_cols)

streak_reset = F.coalesce(F.col("item") != sqlf.lag("item").over(window_spec), True)

cond = sqlf.when(streak_reset, 1).otherwise(0)
streak_id = F.sum(cond).over(window_spec)

streak_spec = Window.partitionBy(partition_cols + [streak_id]).orderBy(order_cols)

streak_counter = F.sum(col).over(streak_spec).alias("streak_counter")
df = df.withColumn(streak_counter)
```

I suspect that Polars might have a way to beat that for concision/clarity, but I haven't come up with one yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another term for the *"streaks"* is *"run-length encoding"*.

Polars has a dedicated [`.rle_id()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rle_id.html#polars.Expr.rle_id) function for getting *"streak IDs"*.

In this specific case, it appears you want:

- the `streak_id` of each `item` per `person`
- the `cum_count` of each `item` per `person, streak_id`

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "person_id": ["alice", "bob", "alice", "bob", "alice", "bob", "alice", "bob"],
    "order_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    "item": ["A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A"]
})
```

```py
(df.with_columns(streak_id = pl.col("item").rle_id().over("person_id"))
   .with_columns(streak_counter = 
      pl.col("item").cum_count().over("person_id", "streak_id")
   )
)
```

```py
shape: (8, 5)
┌───────────┬──────────┬──────┬───────────┬────────────────┐
│ person_id ┆ order_id ┆ item ┆ streak_id ┆ streak_counter │
│ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---            │
│ str       ┆ i64      ┆ str  ┆ u32       ┆ u32            │
╞═══════════╪══════════╪══════╪═══════════╪════════════════╡
│ alice     ┆ 1        ┆ A    ┆ 0         ┆ 1              │
│ bob       ┆ 2        ┆ B    ┆ 0         ┆ 1              │
│ alice     ┆ 3        ┆ B    ┆ 1         ┆ 1              │
│ bob       ┆ 4        ┆ B    ┆ 0         ┆ 2              │
│ alice     ┆ 5        ┆ A    ┆ 2         ┆ 1              │
│ bob       ┆ 6        ┆ B    ┆ 0         ┆ 3              │
│ alice     ┆ 7        ┆ A    ┆ 2         ┆ 2              │
│ bob       ┆ 8        ┆ A    ┆ 1         ┆ 1              │
└───────────┴──────────┴──────┴───────────┴────────────────┘
```

It can also be written in a single expression if preferred:

```py
df.with_columns(streak_counter = 
   pl.col("item").cum_count()
     .over("person_id", pl.col("item").rle_id().over("person_id"))
)
```

```py
shape: (8, 4)
┌───────────┬──────────┬──────┬────────────────┐
│ person_id ┆ order_id ┆ item ┆ streak_counter │
│ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ ---            │
│ str       ┆ i64      ┆ str  ┆ u32            │
╞═══════════╪══════════╪══════╪════════════════╡
│ alice     ┆ 1        ┆ A    ┆ 1              │
│ bob       ┆ 2        ┆ B    ┆ 1              │
│ alice     ┆ 3        ┆ B    ┆ 1              │
│ bob       ┆ 4        ┆ B    ┆ 2              │
│ alice     ┆ 5        ┆ A    ┆ 1              │
│ bob       ┆ 6        ┆ B    ┆ 3              │
│ alice     ┆ 7        ┆ A    ┆ 2              │
│ bob       ┆ 8        ┆ A    ┆ 1              │
└───────────┴──────────┴──────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: That API extension functionality is really cool - your declaration seems simpler than the namespace/decorator approach here: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api.html Is yours just a shortcut/is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @David That's for adding a whole namespace e.g. `pl.col().namespace.foo()`, `pl.col().namespace.bar()`which is different. This example was just adding a single function.

Comment: Also I just realized that this doesn't cover the window case in the original example  – 

`val = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]`
`id = ["alice"] * 4 + ["bob"] * 4`
`df = ({"id": id, "val": val})`

`# gives incorrect result`
`group = (pl.col("val") != pl.col("val").shift()).cumsum()`

 `# errors out with "window expression not allowed in aggregation"`
`group = (pl.col("val") != pl.col("val").over("ids").shift()).cumsum().over("ids")`

Comment: @David Perhaps you can edit the example into your question. What should the correct result be? For the error, just the outmost `.over` should suffice: `group = (pl.col("val") != pl.col("val").shift()).cumsum().over("ids")`

Comment: Ah, that works, thank you - I'll edit a concrete example in.